# Is it posible to detect browser camera without asking user permmision?

Tags: webrtc, getusermedia

Before you all blast me, I know what I'm asking is a considered bad, but I'm not looking for some dodgy underhanded tactic to get to someone's camera without permission.
Let me explaining the reasoning behind the request and hopefully someone can suggest an alternative solution.

I have a e-commerce product page, and on that page I have a button which allows someone to view the product image overlaying their camera to see the product in a their environment (think augmented reality, but not in a 3d space).

What I would like to do is detect if a user has camera capability before I show the button to the "fake AR viewer".
I've used navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia but it prompts the user for camera permission, which when you first land on the page is a bit off-putting "why is the e-commerce site asking for my camera?"

So far the best option I can think of is to detect the web browser and if its mobile and a version that supports video then show the button.

Comment: I would put a “View with AR (requires video camera)” link and only look to see if video cameras are present etc. after the button is pressed. This also tells people who don’t have cameras or have them unplugged that the feature exists.

Answer (score 1):

Use the navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() API. Roughly:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
.then(devices => {
  devices.forEach(device => {
    if (device.kind === 'videoinput') {
      console.log('found camera');
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you wish to detect if a browser is going to ask for a permission with it's own message box and prepare a user for that. Then you may try [Permissions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions):

```
navigator.permissions.query({name: 'camera'}).then(function (permissionStatus) {
  if (permissionStatus.state === 'prompt') {
    // show your own message box here
    // don't forget to pause execution until user reads it, before getUserMedia() call
  }
})
```